# configuration unification Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, configuration

My application outlines are growing. I am looking for some solution to store configurations for each circuit.
I think that such a configuration format would be nice :

```
someHost:
  test: testUrl
  local: localUrl
  dev: devUrl
  qa: qaUrl
  stage: stageUrl
  prod: prodUrl
```

So far, I don’t have an understanding of how to properly configure my application so that it works correctly with the necessary configurations depending on the profile. Do you have any solution?

Stack: Java, Spring Boot 2, Kubernetes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep format you propose you will need to create another variable where you will configure prefix.

```
hostPrefix: dev
someHost:
  test: testUrl
  local: localUrl
  dev: devUrl
  qa: qaUrl
  stage: stageUrl
  prod: prodUrl
```

Then inject it with @Value in required field with inner placeholders:

```
@Value("${someHost.${hostPrefix}}")
private String url;
```

Thats it. In current solution it will be resolved to `${someHost.dev}`, which would be resolved to `devUrl`. You can also use spring profile for that:

```
@Value("${someHost.${spring.profiles}}")
private String url;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Spring's profiles](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles) for that. 
Define a profile per environment, and then it can have it's own set of properties and beans

Comment: this will force me to do under each contour of the bean depending on the environment. I would like to have only 1 bean, which would understand what configuration it needs depending on the profile

Comment: You don't have to change any bean if you don't like to. Don't use profile annotation and the bean will be relevant for all. You can simply divide your properties file to a file per profile

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you already have configuration in yml format. Then you can use spring profiles like this:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
someHost:
  url: devUrl
---
spring:
  profiles: test
someHost:
  url: testUrl
---
spring:
  profiles: qa
someHost:
  url: qaUrl
```

And then you create `@Configuration`:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("someHost")
public class SomeHostConfig {

    private String url;
}
```

Or you can use any managed bean field and inject it with @Value:

```
@Value("${someHost.url}")
private String someHostUrl;
```

Then you run your application with profile. For example, in maven it would be:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=dev
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but I would like to make the configuration file as clear and compact as possible. Therefore, I am looking for a solution for the format I proposed.